# use 一触即発 to refer to someone's personality? someone who "easily gets upset"?

Tags: set-phrases

I think "一触即発" can be used to refer to the personality of a person and means **"quick to anger or get emotionally upset"**. *If it cannot, please just say "no it cannot" and no reason to read further.*

This is how I think it can be used:

**talking directly to the person**:
「さすが一触即発の性格でしょうね。えと、なのに、ふつつかな私を許してください。申し訳ありません。」 (*You have such a personality that is quick to anger. Um, anyway, please make allowances for my incompetence. I have no excuse.*)

**talking with someone about a third person who is not present (Tanaka-san)**:
「田中さんは一触即発の人だと思わない。」(*Do you think that Tanaka-san is quick to anger?*)

1. Does it make sense to even refer to a personality as 一触即発? Does it sound funny, make a native speaker laugh? Or, a personality cannot be defined that way?
2. Should it be "一触即発の人" or "一触即発の性格がある人"?
3. Either way, it is very informal / humorous way among friends to describe someone who easily gets upset?
4. 人柄 instead of 性格?

Comment: @nodakai Please try to avoid answering questions in the comment section.

Comment: @snailcar and removing my comment was the best thing you could do for the benefit of the community? Awesome.

Comment: @nodakai I think so.  Users flagged it asking for it to be removed, and as a moderator, I’m trying to do what the community wants.  Please feel free to post answers as answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a bit awkward to use 「一触即発」for describing one's personality which is *short-temper, getting upset easily, etc.* since the expression is normally used to describe that **something dangerous/unwanted** will be triggered on the spot when an action taken.

I guess the word more suitable is「瞬間湯沸かし器」: instaneous water boiler or 「すぐカチンとくる」: easily losing temper for what you imagine.

If you want to use 「一触即発」, the sentence came up to me is 「〇〇さんは喧嘩早いので、いつも一触即発の事態になる」: *Since 〇〇 are bellicose, we are always getting into a powder keg.*

However, it seems the phrase「一触即発の人」is not so odd to me. Probably it could be used between your friends for making fun of them because of their humorous behaviour. So, it depends.

I think「一触即発の性格」would be better than「一触即発の人柄」since 「人柄」is basically used to describe one’s personality affirmatively.

Comment: I felt impelled to click +1 for 瞬間湯沸かし器